# Vulnerabilities of @typescript/eslint-plugin?

Tags: reactjs, security, tslint, typescript-eslint

There are two packages, TSLint,

https://github.com/palantir/tslint

and it's overcomer, typescript-eslint,

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint

They have some same maintainer. typescript-eslint is referring to the older one in it's documentation.

Palantir is a company, that has not only with its name a twilighting taste, and I'm not sure, that this is a safe package. Their products are seen as insightful for some and as spyware for others. So it's not totally clear, if it is a benevolent contribution to the public or there might be something about it, that should be seen critical.

Especially if we have to care about personal data in our app. @typescript/eslint-plugin cannot be removed from a build environment of Create-React-App with typescript, because it is also the "parser", mentioned in ".eslintrc".

How to calm down the troubles? How to be sure, there is no leak? Or can I exclude it from the node_modules folder and be able to get a "build" from create-react-app?

The AST-scanning of a parser allows also to insert functionality to capture all content, flowing through the functions. It's easily possible to write your own rule, that can deploy a bunch of wrappers on every function call, that sends all your information to some location and needs just to be applied with eslint --fix in every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint is not a vulnerability vector because it only touches ***source code***. This means that in order for it to compromise your code, you have to do the following:

1. install a compromised eslint plugin.
2. manually turn on the compromised eslint rule.
3. run the compromised autofix via `eslint --fix`.
4. ignore the changes to your source code and ship the compromised code to production.

(1) & (2) are enough of a hurdle that it's not going to happen, or if it does then someone will very quickly detect the compromise and report a security problem.
(3) requires manual action by an engineer to cause.
(4) can easily be caught by any peer review process before merging your code,  because again; eslint operates solely on source code.

create-react-app is also properly configured such that it will ensure eslint does not run on your build code. AFAIK - it also does not run ESLint when doing a production build either.

---

Modern JS development (like any language development that relies upon third-party code) is built upon a chain-of-trust. You trust that the packages you install and their dependencies are safe. CRA has decided that eslint, typescript-eslint, et al are all trusted - thus they include them as dependencies.

If you trust CRA, then you must trust its dependencies as well.

If you don't trust CRA or one of its dependencies - then you don't install it, and you build your own in-house solution.

---

tslint is safe, and always has been. If plantir was some shady company and injected malware into their package - someone would very quickly find it and report a vulnerability - destroying the credibility of the project and the company.

typescript-eslint has no relationship to palantir or tslint. The projects are entirely separate - they have different maintainers, and typescript-eslint is owned by no company.

typescript-eslint (like tslint) is also completely open source - if you're worried about anything - you can just spend the time verifying it is safe yourself.

typescript-eslint (like tslint) is also shipped to NPM (and thus to your computer) as un-obfuscated, unminified JS. You can easily spend the time to verify that the code you've received matches the code in the OSS repo and is safe.

Comment: Three points: 
(1) Joshua Goldberg is a common maintainer of both projects (https://github.com/JoshuaKGoldberg/Goldblog/blob/3c5bfc4d9e30df751d4b424c11f1c46f48e990e4/content/blog/tslint-maintenance/index.md) 
(2) Why can't the typescript-eslint dependency only be used as dev-dependency? If I delete it from `node_modules` the build process fails, because it is used to remove typescript from the AST. — So it must run for all production builds using typescript, that is default anyway with CRA. 
(3) Who reads the eslint-plugin-code?
But yes, let's trust, if there is nothing concrete about it.

Comment: Josh is also a contributor to TypeScript itself. He does a hell of a lot to push forward the state of the TS ecosystem. If you research him, you'll quickly learn this and that he can be trusted. Your build fails because CRA depends on it. It's likely imported within the webpack config it configures for you. So if you delete it entirely, the config can't require it, and everything crashes. Again - you could investigate CRA to understand how it uses the package if you'd like, rather than assuming it's malicious.

Comment: In case you didn't know - I am the core maintainer of typescript-eslint, and have been for last 3 years. The TypeScript project endorses the project as the recommended linting solution for TS. They also use it within their repos. So if you don't trust this project, then you can't trust TypeScript or really anything on NPM.

Comment: Hi, Josh Goldberg here, +1 to everything Brad is saying. I'd like to note that I have no affiliation with Palantir. Never have and probably never will.